# How to UPDATE sql every file in folder

Tags: php

I have function that will remove in 7 days by default. If i have set Folder expire in 30 days, file in that folder will be delete in 7 days by default. 
so I want to set Timeup_limit every file inside, but I dont know how to use recursive to update every file.

```
public static function setTimeuplimitFile( $itemSource, $dateLimit) {

    $query = \OC_DB::prepare('UPDATE `oc_filecache` SET `timeup_limit` = ? WHERE `fileid` = ?');
    $query->bindValue(1, $dateLimit);
    $query->bindValue(2, $itemSource);
    $query->execute();
    return true;
}
```

---

And function for Folder #Updated

```
public static function setTimeuplimitFolder($itemSource, $dateLimit) {

    $query = \OC_DB::prepare('UPDATE `oc_filecache` SET `timeup_limit` = ? WHERE `fileid` = ?');
    $query->bindValue(1, $dateLimit);
    $query->bindValue(2, $itemSource);
    $query->execute();


    $query2 = \OC_DB::prepare('SELECT mimetype,fileid FROM`oc_filecache` WHERE `parent` = ?');
    $r = $query2->execute(array($itemSource));

    if ($r) {
        while($row = $r->fetchRow()){
            if($row["mimetype"] == 2){ //mimetype = 2 is folder
                OCP\Share::setTimeuplimitFolder($row["fileid"],$dateLimit);
            }
            else{ //file
                $query = \OC_DB::prepare('UPDATE `oc_filecache` SET `timeup_limit` = ? WHERE `fileid` = ?');
                $query->bindValue(1, $dateLimit);
                $fileid = $row["fileid"];
                $query->bindValue(2, $fileid);
                $query->execute();

            }
        }
    }




    return true;
}
```

[image]

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_query($query2)` instead of the `\OC_DB::prepare()` that you have on every other query?

Comment: Thank you @Sean It's work now. I really confusing on this.

Comment: but i have still problem with recursive function.

Comment: is this `PDO`? `->fetchRow()` is not a `PDO` method.